# how to use nested module's alias name?

Tags: elixir

My code is as follows, `Mechanics.Disk.InventoryMap.Shelf` is nested, I want to use it by alias name `Shelf`, and compiler gives error message

```
defmodule Mechanics.Disk.InventoryMap do
  alias __MODULE__
  alias Mechanics.Disk.InventoryMap.Shelf
defmodule Mechanics.Disk.InventoryMap.Shelf do
  @enforce_keys [:shelfIdX,:shelfIdY,:shelfIdZ]
  defstruct [:shelfIdX,
    :shelfIdY,
    :shelfIdZ
    ]
end
def new(LibraryTemplate, lineSize,levelSize) do
  for i <- 0..lineSize,j <- 0..levelSize,k <- [0,1] do
    {{i,j,k},%Shelf{shelfIdX: i,shelfIdY: j, shelfIdZ: k}} # <---- error here
  end
end
```

Error message is as follows:

```
[{
    "resource": "/Users/yuchen/Documents/Project/CY2/mechanics/lib/mechanics/disk/InventoryMap.ex",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#0",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "(CompileError) Mechanics.Disk.InventoryMap.Shelf.__struct__/1 is undefined, cannot expand struct Mechanics.Disk.InventoryMap.Shelf. Make sure the struct name is correct. If the struct name exists and is correct but it still cannot be found, you likely have cyclic module usage in your code",
    "source": "Elixir",
    "startLineNumber": 49,
    "startColumn": 5,
    "endLineNumber": 49,
    "endColumn": 59
}]
```

Comment: you want to reference a module that was not yet compiled, have you tried moving the nested module to another file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referencing the *struct* in the module that has not yet been compiled (as pointed out by @Daniel in the comments.)

One way to solve it would be to move the struct into another file. Another way would be to avoid the explicit *struct* syntax sugar `%Shelf{}` (which involves struct type checks under the hood) using [`struct!/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#struct!/2) as shown below

```elixir
defmodule Mechanics.Disk.InventoryMap do
  alias __MODULE__
  alias Mechanics.Disk.InventoryMap.Shelf

  defmodule Mechanics.Disk.InventoryMap.Shelf do
    @enforce_keys ~w|shelfIdX shelfIdY shelfIdZ|a
    defstruct ~w|shelfIdX shelfIdY shelfIdZ|a
  end

  def new(LibraryTemplate, line_size, level_size) do
    for i <- 0..line_size, j <- 0..level_size, k <- [0,1] do
      {{i, j, k}, struct!(Shelf, shelfIdX: i, shelfIdY: j, shelfIdZ: k)}
    end
  end
end
```

*Sidenote:* by convention, [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir) uses snake casing.

Comment: Thank you for your 'snake casing' remind.